# URL Encoding issue in URI Scheme in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone-8.1

I've implemented custom protocol URI Scheme in Windows Phone with following two types of URL:

`scheme://open?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F%3Fparam1%3D1%26param2%3D2`

`scheme://open?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&param1=1&param2=2`

Both URIs are coming same in ActivatedEventArgs in Windows Phone 8.1 and it works fine on android/windows desktop app. The URI parameter is following in both cases:

`scheme://open?url=http://stackoverflow.com/&param1=1&param2=2`

Following is function called on URI browsing:

```
    protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
        {
            var _args = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
            Uri uri = _args.Uri;//same uri in both cases
        }
        base.OnActivated(args);
    }
```

Comment: What is it that is not working?

Comment: The value of different parameters is coming in same way and the URL is decoded. So I'm not able to differentiate whether the param1 belongs to current URL or the to the URL passed in parameter.

Comment: but ```&param1=1&param2=2``` are not parameters of ```http://stackoverflow.com/&param1=1&param2=2``` because the first ```&``` should be a ```?```

Comment: `scheme://open?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F%3Fparam3%3D3%26param1%3D1%26param2%3D2`

`scheme://open?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F%3Fparam3%3D3&param1=1&param2=2`


This would result in 

`http://stackoverflow.com/?param3=3&param1=1&param2=2`